# Android ListView default onHold(?) color

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

For my list view, each row holds a view (which is a custom view that extends LinearLayout). However, the blue highlighting doesn't appear when you do an onHold action on a list view item. In my experience, this is default, for which you don't even need to code for. How does one turn on or turn off this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of turning it on or off. It's actually on, but you can't see it.

The "on hold color" effect is achieved via the ListView's [selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3alistSelector). It's a state list drawable, means it's displayed differently depending on the view's state (e.g. pressed, selected, enabled, checked, &c).

The only problem is that this selector is drawn behind the item view. Therefore, if the item view is opaque (i.e. it has a non-transparent background) it won't be visible.

The easiest solution is to make your own background a state drawable, and make it **transparent** when the item is selected, hence the built-in selector will be visible. Another option, if you want, is to set your own selection color, via the same method.

Please check Romain Guy's [World of ListView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) from I/O 2010, around the 31:00 mark (slides [here](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf), it's on slide 36).

Comment: Ah yes, you were correct. I had previously set the background to an opaque color. I just removed the setBackgroundColor(R.color.my_opaque) and I can see the hold color. Thanks for the tip about the state drawable as well.